# JavaFX 2.x TableView localization

Tags: localization, tableview, javafx-2

When TableView control contains no content, it displays "No content in table". How to change/localize that string?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you go

```
tableView.setPlaceholder(new Text("Your localized text here"));
```

Comment: Ha, it's a node :) and I was looking for some string setter or localization bundle.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no things display in table view if no data

```
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: lightyellow;
}

.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following JavaFX recommendation it'd be better to implement like this

Model.java

```
class Model {
    private final ObjectProperty<Text> placeholderProperty;

    Model(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        placeholderProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Text(resourceBundle.getString("placeholderTextFromLocalizationProperties")));
    }

    ...

    ObjectProperty<Text> placeholderProperty() {
        return placeholderProperty;
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
class Controller implements Initializable {
    private Model model;
    @FXML
    private TableView tableView;
    ...
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        model = new Model(resourceBundle);

        tableView.setPlaceholder(model.placeholderProperty().get());

    }
    ...
}
```

When you are about to change localization everything you need is to edit your property file.